# Extend chechbox clickable area without label

Tags: html, css

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="hovereffect">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/some-image" alt="">
    <input type="checkbox" class="img-checkbox">
</div>

.hovereffect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .img-checkbox{
    position: absolute;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    top: 3px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image: image with checkbox]

So there is the checkbox in the right upper corner over the image and would like to extend the clickable are to the whole image for a better user experience.

As you can see the checkbox has no label and I would like to achieve the goal without a label.

I tried tricks with the ::after element which kinda worked with chrome but not really with firefox and I couldn't make the clickable area responsive that is to say, extend to the whole area of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use Javascript/jQuery?

You can start by assigning unique `id` to every image you have (Ex: *img1,img2,img3*) and every checkbox associated to the image (Ex: *img1-checkbox*).Then you can use the code below:

`$('#img1').click(
    $('#img1-checkbox').attr('checked', true);
);`

Or something like that.

Comment: the thing is its a media library im building and there are many images there so i would need to add unique class names to all images. Your suggestion is good. I could do it with jquery/js but it maybe too much unnecessary js code that could be solved with css. right?

Comment: `class` is mentioned in common for a group of elements and `id` is for individual elements (unique). So, you can assign `id` to your images and then use those **ids** in your jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css) since a very long time and you simply **cannot**  achieve your goal with pure css. The only available ways of getting it done are ou using `label` or `jquery/javascript` or `:after` pseudo class.

If you want to expand the checkbox size, then try this:

```
.hovereffect input[type=checkbox]
{
  width:100px !important; //adjust as per need
  height:100px !important; //adjust as per need
}
```

This will increase the clickable area of the checkbox field. [Working Link](http://codepen.io/hariharker/pen/BzVdxv)

But, if you want the `checkbox` to be **transparent** and show the image behind, then you will have to use label and set it's background color to transparent.

I'm waiting to see someone prove me wrong with working code.